# Change each Windows audio mixer

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, npm-package

I'm currently trying to develop software for Windows with typescript.
I would like to change the audio being played on Windows using the mixer for each application.  Just like the audio mixer that comes with Windows.

I found a plug-in called [win-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-audio) that can change the volume, but only the master volume can be changed.

Are there any plugins that support Windows per-application audio mixers?  Or do I need to implement C++ separately?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To develop per-application audio mixers for Windows, you'll likely need to use C++ or a similar low-level language. This functionality typically cannot be achieved using TypeScript or high-level languages and libraries.

To implement per-application audio mixing, you can consider using the Windows Core Audio API (WASAPI). WASAPI allows you to interact with the Windows audio system at a lower level, enabling you to control audio for each application. You would need to write a C++ application to access audio sessions and control volume and other properties.

Alternatively, you can explore existing third-party C++ libraries like AudioRouter, which provide higher-level interfaces for controlling audio for individual applications. These libraries can reduce the amount of work required to implement audio mixing from scratch.

Keep in mind that interacting with the Windows audio system can be complex, and it requires a deep understanding of Windows audio programming. Therefore, I recommend delving into Windows audio programming and considering C++ or another appropriate language for this task before proceeding with implementation.